# Causes for inconsistent behavior when adding NaNs to a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, python-internals

There is puzzling (at least for me) behavior of Python's set in combination with `NaN`s ([here live](https://ideone.com/L6XzmM)):

```
>>> float('nan') in {float('nan')}    # example 1
False
>>> nan = float('nan')                # example 2
>>> nan in {nan}
True
```

At first, I wrongly assumed,that this is the behavior of the `==`-operator, but this is obviously not the case because both cases yield `False` as expected ([here live](https://ideone.com/svs3Y8)):

```
>>> float('nan') == float('nan') 
False
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> nan == nan
False
```

I'm mainly interested in the causes for this behavior. But if there is a way to ensure consistent behavior, that would also be nice to know!

Comment: Python's containers assume that `==` is an equivalence relation. If it's not, notions of containment fall apart. You shouldn't be putting NaN in a set in the first place.

Comment: Probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089400/python-set-in-operator-uses-equality-or-identity

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320022/why-in-numpy-nan-nan-is-false-while-nan-in-nan-is-true).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set membership does an identity check as a short-circuit before considering an equality check (CPython source is in [`setobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c), see also the note below [`PyObject_RichCompareBool`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompareBool)).

Python core devs are motivated by these invariants:

```
for a in container:
    assert a in container    # this should ALWAYS be true
```

Ergo:

```
assert a in [a]
assert a in (a,)
assert a in {a}
```

It was decided that ensuring these invariants was the most important priority, and as for NaN: oh well.  *Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules*. For all the gory details, see bpo **issue4296**:

[Python assumes identity implies equivalence; contradicts NaN](https://bugs.python.org/issue4296#msg75735).