# Why does `myfloat in myset` become super slow?

Tags: python, performance, set

When I re-insert the same `float` value into my set a few times, the `x in s` check that should take constant time becomes very slow. Why?

Output of timing `x in s`:

```
   0.06 microseconds
   0.09 microseconds
   0.16 microseconds
   0.56 microseconds
   1.00 microseconds
   1.58 microseconds
   2.55 microseconds
   5.98 microseconds
  10.50 microseconds
  24.54 microseconds
  40.39 microseconds
  96.60 microseconds
 160.24 microseconds
 419.08 microseconds
 732.27 microseconds
```

Code  ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3bCsIwEETf8xX7UpJIKa1FFKFfIiJpm9RAcyGJUBG/PaYXivOy7MzuGfsOT6Pri3UxCmcUBKm4DCCVNS5sG0IeGviI0bBAsGYa0y8SxsEDpAbH9MBJdaJXBEm7fzv4@2rNmhLhH7AHvmB9T6bVmPvS4VpL8DRzPM5Bv1TLXVOVZZnDMJqWjb7ZJqEUDlDxeiFYJ3X6zM7FUYCSnTOed0b3HkO2cGmMPw)):

```
from timeit import timeit

s = {float('nan')}
for _ in range(15):
    for _ in [*s]:
        x = float('nan')
        s.add(x)
    time = timeit('x in s', number=1000, globals=globals()) * 1e3
    print('%7.2f microseconds' % time)
```

Comment: Related: [Causes for inconsistent behavior when adding NaNs to a set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51622065/674039)

Comment: You may be interested to know that this is "fixed" in Python 3.10: with your code, I get 433.57µs from the final iteration when running under Python 3.9.9, and 0.04µs under Python 3.10.1. See https://bugs.python.org/issue43475 for more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are using **nan**, which is notorious for breaking naive expectations regarding `__hash__`/`__eq__` contract... i.e.:

```
>>> myset = set()
>>> myset.add(float('nan'))
>>> myset
{nan}
>>> myset.add(float('nan'))
>>> myset
{nan, nan}
```

This happens because:

```
>>> float('nan') == float('nan')
False
```

But:

```
>>> hash(float('nan')) == hash(float('nan'))
True
```

So you are guaranteed to collide every time, and you are seeing hash set behavior degrade to O(N), which is the worst-case behavior, not O(1). Fundamentally, you *are not re-inserting the same float value*.

Moreover, watch out for this behavior:

```
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> myset = set()
>>> myset.add(nan)
>>> myset.add(nan)
>>> myset
{nan}
```

Despite:

```
>>> nan == nan
False
```

The above is due to an optimization, that for containers, Python actually checks identity first to avoid potentially costly `__eq__` operations. Since I re-used the same object, now it is being considered "the same value".

Comment: Exactly, you've turned the (degenerate) hash set into a  linked list

Comment: @Alexander yes, although to be clear I'm pretty sure Python hash-based container use open addressing for collision resolution

Comment: Ah, then it's a linear array scan (roughly). Better, but still O(n), like you mentioned

Comment: What's the contract that is broken?

Comment: I see *"The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value"* [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__). And nan doesn't break that.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode that objects with the "same value" (i.e. "equal each other"). have the same hash value.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode alternatively, you can also just realize that NaN is not the same value as NaN, by *definition*, NaN is not the same value *as any float*. So it isn't breaking the contract exactly, but the common expectation that NaN is the same value as NaN.

Comment: But they *do* have the same hash value, as you showed. And they don't even have to, as they *don't* compare equal. So that's rather doubly not breaking the contract.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I still don't think it's about that contract, but rather just about the expectation that nan equals itself. Btw, this was inspired by a comment saying it [involves no looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68996444/in-operator-functionality-in-python/68997344#comment121940473_68996444).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode yeah, that's what I reworded it to.

Comment: One more thing: Of course I was sure you knew it can degrade, just took your comment as challenge since I hadn't actually seen it degrade before. And then thought it's interesting enough to share, and maybe useful to reference ([didn't take long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69017839/69020401#comment121979563_69017911)). I'm not happy having resorted to the nan hammer, though. Might try to reverse-engineer int hashing to get a set of let's say 96-bit ints with equal hashes. Or do you have another idea to create equal-hash sets? (Other than custom class, of course.)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I'm not sure what this is supposed to demonstrate about my comment.

Comment: I mean they talked about a "loop behind the scene" and you responded that it doesn't involve looping, but it does. Just not the kind of loop that they and you meant.

Comment: Finding equal-hash ints was easier than I expected: `all(hash(i*(2**61-1)) == 0 for i in range(10**6))`.