# Most suitable data structure to support delete from left and delete from arbitrary index where delete from left is twice as much frequent

Tags: python, performance

I am writing a function that takes a large list of strings and classifies them.

Each string classified is deleted from the list one after another.

Sometimes the function needs to delete a string in an arbitrary index and sometimes it needs to delete a string from the leftmost position.

The ratio between these two cases is about 2/3 of the times it deletes from the leftmost position and 1/3 of the time from an arbitrary place in the middle.

I know using list as the data structure to hold the strings is **O(n)** deleting the leftmost cell and **O(n-i)** deleting the i'th cell, since it moves all the cells to the right one step left for each deletion.

I then tried using `collections.deque` instead of list, but it actually took more time (about 4/3 more time) than the original `list` data structure, possibly because of the arbitrary place deletions.

What data structure will perform best under these assumptions? Is there any better than just using a `list`?

The deletions with the `list` data structure from leftmost cell with is using `list.pop(0)` and removing from arbitrary index is by value using `list.remove(value)`.

Comment: show us exactly how you are using the deque

Comment: How large is the list, and how do you find those arbitrary indexes?

Comment: Just using `leftpop()` for deleting from left and `remove(index)` for deleting in arbitrary index

Comment: Perhaps reverse your list (and adjust the algorithm accordingly) so you delete from the right instead?

Comment: Or perhaps do lazy deletions, i.e., instead of deleting at arbitrary indexes, replace the value with `None` and delete it when you come across it later (when it's the last list element). We could help you better if you told us more about your overall procedure.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode ~ one million strings, the procedure can sometimes classify a string and then deduce the classification of other related strings, hence deleting them by value from the list

Comment: So when you delete them "by value", how do you know where they are?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode These are the arbitrary position deletions

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. My point is that slowness might rather be a result of how you find the deletion indexes instead of the actual deletions.

Comment: I just use `list.remove(value)`

Comment: So exactly what I thought.

Comment: Yes, the first comment was misleading. I edited the post and added this description.

Comment: I don't have time now and would like to know more to proceed anyway, but have a look at this [demo](https://tio.run/##pY7LCsIwEEX3@YrZSNJaSlUUKfRLxEVqkzaQF9NR8OtjqF240oXLe@dc5sQnTcEfzhFT0hgckHHKEBgXA9KaGJPQwYXrEPgVStg1ZXmCbW56iWvTMMrMmxdWun6QLcgalQsPJRawqMDfXa@wy3ixrFhE40nwBTN@BJl/TgrQjBO1vAK@OdZ7zWEDlIMz1ppZ3YIfZl78oRVDFM0Xn3yPHzpWaWoBfvik9AI).

Comment: ```Deque``` is suitable for this case. I don't understand why it's slower in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) with your strings as keys.

Benchmark with just 30,000 strings,  20,000 deletions from left and 10,000 "arbitrary" removals:

```
1476 ms  1490 ms  1491 ms  using_list
  10 ms    11 ms    11 ms  using_OrderedDict
```

Instead of

```
strings_list.pop(0)
strings_list.remove(value)
```

use

```
strings_dict.popitem(False)
strings_dict.pop(value)
```

This assumes you have no duplicate strings, which seems likely. If you do, then use the dictionary values as the frequencies.

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVPbSsQwEH3vVwyImEgpXXYfZMEXEV/9AJES21k32FxIZpX9@jVJ021dXVADJZ2cuZwzmdg9bY1e3lh3OGycUUBSoSSQyhpH2SoS0pq@x5ak0X6EH12HDrt72WYfJ3QXtgxHK3yvWBQdbmDnpX5teumJeXLh35fgUJl39HxdQFgb42CAQOoRG6C4clRljWU1/@3xkCaX5HMqM/rnGOVjuJ1rraLWN9z7MYr/kb0kVOxB9B75P@BJygXc7WTfAaGnVniED0lbWNZlXdeAPSrU5ItJQ@q9EilDCelq2KJugncJq7RzzovW2H1wHitGk/Ei6wnA03MRpTZJ5SxHbln0n9/FqS1DiuNksB41ix58AHOVSliLumPHWMkHuajbrRLu7ZTBcjZBm51uIzLNW/n9wqd7iTOeZY1HZ5KP6@cGzT0owMPbYb1QL51YJ1ZJzzRiJeidekF3uziJjozGFhD/yrTy4WnNytlAgtg1u7pcdaA8XMElMIJrWOCSJyUUlaTYUDHSqJpGC4VNM2QZMvDD4RM)):

```
from timeit import timeit
from collections import OrderedDict
from random import randrange

def using_list(strings, removes):
    for string in removes:
        strings.pop(0)
        strings.pop(0)
        strings.remove(string)

def using_OrderedDict(strings, removes):
    strings = OrderedDict.fromkeys(strings)
    for string in removes:
        strings.popitem(False)
        strings.popitem(False)
        strings.pop(string)

# Build testcase with 30,000 elements
strings = list(map(str, range(10_000, 40_000)))
copy = strings.copy()
removes = []
for _ in range(10_000):
    copy.pop(0)
    copy.pop(0)
    i = randrange(len(copy))
    removes.append(copy.pop(i))

# Benchmark
for _ in range(3):
    for func in using_list, using_OrderedDict:
        times = []
        for _ in range(3):
            copy = strings.copy()
            t = timeit(lambda: func(copy, removes), number=1)
            times.append(t)
        times.sort()
        print(*('%4d ms ' % (t * 1e3) for t in times), func.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: I'm amazed this worked so fast, days became just minutes

Answer (score 1):

If you know where you exactly want to delete, you might be looking for a [linked list implementation](https://pypi.org/project/llist/)

Do note that deletion from a linked list is [O(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20a%20linked,which%20together%20represent%20a%20sequence.)

However, searching for an element is O(n)

EDIT:
If you instead care about values to be deleted, a [set](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp) is probably what you're looking for. Do note that set is an unordered datastructure and would only allow for values to be deleted

Comment: Depends on how they find the deletion index. If they actually don't come from an index but from a *value* to delete, they could use a dict mapping the values to linked list nodes. Then "searching" should be O(1) as well.

Comment: but I believe that using a dict is O(logn(n)) tho

Comment: No, it's O(1), except for very special cases (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69017358/16759116) but for dict). Especially for strings, as there's randomization involved so it's hard to make it slow even if you try.