# does pythons keyword "in" check for "is" or for "=="

Tags: python, python-3.x, identity, equality

What exactly does the keyword `in` check for in python, generally? equality, identity, something else?

Example:

Suppose I have two classes X and Y with different `__eq__` operators

```
class X:
  def __eq__(self,other):
    return False

class Y:
  def __eq__(self,other):
    return True
```

Now I can do

```
a = X()
b = a
k = [a]
b in k # -> True
```

This suggests a check for identity to me.
But I can also do

```
c = Y()
d = Y()
c is d # -> False
l = [d]
c in l # -> True
```

which suggests a check for equality. The only theory I came up with is that it first checks for identity, and if this is not the case, then check for equality. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. It checks for identity and then equality.

Comment: Your `==` would be entirely broken if `a is b` is `True` but `a == b` is `False`. Equality is, by definition, reflexive: `x == x` for all `x`.

Comment: @chepner mathematically this is ofc absolutely true, but i was curious about the python internals.

Comment: @chepner That's the schizophrenic object pattern…

Comment: @chepner There are objects for which `x!=x`. E.g. `float('nan')` is not equal to itself.

Comment: `in` itself uses *neither*; see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations.

Comment: @chepner thats what i was looking for: equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`

Comment: @kawillzocken That's only true for some types, not `in` in general.

Comment: Related but not a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9089400/1394393

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking containment on a **list** is equivalent to looking for identity or equality on each element.

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations):

> For container types such as **list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque**,
>   the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`

(With the caveat that the objects in a hash-based container, like a set, must have a hash implementation that is consistent with their definition of equality.)

For user-defined container types, the behaviour of `in` is determined by the `__contains__` method.

Comment: Unless, of course, the container defines a `__contains__` method, e.g. for testing the hashcode first... which should also be the case for `set` etc., so that documentation can not really be accurate, right?

Comment: or if it defines `__getitem__` FWIW.

Comment: You can also have fun with Russell's Paradox by defining `__contains__ = lambda *args: True`.

Comment: @khelwood you may want to update your answer to make clear that this extract only applies to some of the builtins containers...

Comment: @khelwood err... indeed, my bad, I didn't spot it. But then you should possibly make it more proeminent (bold text for example...) xD

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Very well. I have emboldened my text.

Answer (score 4):

The true answer is that by itself, `in` doesn't do any test - it's up to the container (the object after `in` in your expression) implementation. `in` will actually invoke either `container.__contains__(obj)`  if it's defined, else `container.__getitem__(obj)`, and return the result. How the container implements the test (identity, equality, arcane algorithm based on the moon's phase and the captain's birthdate) is the container's concerns.

Comment: You could  add "hashcode" as as example for another (actual) containment test.