# using "in" operator with set and list yields different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, pytorch, python-itertools

I found a difference when using the "*in*" operator in python but I cannot find the reason behind it. To see the difference check out the minimal example I provide below (note that even though the example uses pytorch, I do not think this is a torch related thing):

```py
import torch
a = torch.Tensor(2,3)
b = torch.Tensor(2)

# case 1a:
b  in list([a,a,b]) # raises an error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (2) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension 0

# case 1b
b in set([a,a,b]) # True (i.e. no error)
```

As you can see when *in* operator is used with a *list* it raises an error, but if it is used with a *set* it raises no error and successfully manages to check if the provided element exists in the data structure.

What is the reason behind this and how can I use *list* to prevent this error ?
Thank you.

Comment: You're going to need to provide some versions here because I can't get even the setup code working with pytorch `2.1.1`

Comment: ... added to that, you're aware you have `.tensor()` and `.Tensor()` in the example? They're different

Comment: @roganjosh my versions are (Python 3.8.16 with torch 2.0.1), but I do not think that it matters much.

Comment: Your typo does. I have it running now by fixing that

Comment: @NikoFohr Are you sure that it is by pure luck, and if so could you give me 100% proof way of doing this please.

Comment: @cangozpi Are you aware that `a == b` raises that error? The problem boils does to whether the membership test attempts to compare `a` and `b`. Are you familiar with how `set` works "under the hood"?

Comment: @Brian61354270 no I don't know about the details of python's internal set implementation. You are right that ```a == b``` is the issue when these tensor's sizes do not match but how can I avoid that. I do not care for _==_ operation, it can also be _is_.

Comment: @cangozpi See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table for the basics, which emphasis on section on open addressing for collision resolution. `set` uses `==` after a hash lookup to check for whether a hash collision occurred. No matter what you do, if you have have incomparable entries in a set like this, you're gambling that a hash collision will never occur.

Comment: If you're okay with relying on object identity instead of equality, you can trying using a `dict` with object `id`s as the keys. E.g. `id(b) in {id(a): a, id(b): b}`. Or if you don't need to access the values, you can use a `set` of `id`s: `id(b) in {id(a), id(b)}`.

Answer (score 1):

*Part of the explanation is pytorch specific. That's perhaps the less interesting part, so I put that in the end. The first part of the explanation is more broadly about how the `in`  operator works in the python language.*

### How `x in collection`  works in python?

It depends on the type of [Data Structure](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) used. In particular, data structures using an internal hashtable (sets and dictionaries) work differently than data structures without hashtables, like lists and sets. The algorithm is basically, for every element `c` in the collection:

##### Collections NOT using hashtable (lists, tuples, ..)

How `x in collection` works internally when `collection`  is a list or tuple. (pseudocode)

```py
def is_in(x, collection):
  for c in collection:
      if (x is c or x==c):
          return True
  return False
```

- compare first identity (`is`) and if identity is not same, compare equality (`==`)
- every element `c`  in the collection is compared to `x`, in order, *until the first match*.

##### Collections using a hashtable (sets, dicts, ..)

How `x in collection` works internally when `collection`  is a set or dictionary.

*There is no such function as get_subset_by_hash in python; this is just some pseudocode*

```py
def is_in(x, collection):
  # Select elements c from collection for which hash(x) == hash(c) 
  subset = get_subset_by_hash(collection, hash(x))
  for c in subset:
      if (x is c or x==c):
          return True
  return False
```

- First, take the subset `subset` of elements in `collection` which match with hash equality check. *This is the part which makes set lookup fast*.
- Then, iterate over the `subset`  and do similar comparison with every element `c` (first identity, then equality), and *stop on first match*. The `subset`  is typically 1 or just few elements even for very large datasets.
- Note: The hash for elements in the collection is calculated when the item is added to the collection, and the hash for the `x` is calculated when using the `in`  operator.

##### References for: `x in collection`

The first part can be read from python documentation for [Membership test operations](https://docs.python.org/3.12/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations):

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or
> collections.deque, the expression x in y is equivalent to any(x is e
> or x == e for e in y).

In my opinion the documentation oversimplifies the expression with sets and alike as there really is first a hash value check. I could not find this in the official documentation, but found a Python core developer (Raymond Hettinger) explaining [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9091138/3015186) that the "`hash(x) == hash(c) and..`"  is added to the start with sets

### Hands-on `x in collection` tests

For this, let's create a custom class `MyObj` with its own hash calculation logic (for `hash(x)`) and it's own `__eq__` logic (for  `x == c`  checks):

```py
class MyObj:
    def __init__(self, val, hashval):
        self._val = val
        self._hashval = hashval

    def __hash__(self):
        print(f"{str(self)} calling __hash__")
        return self._hashval

    def __eq__(self, other):
        print(f"{str(self)} calling __eq__, {other=}")
        return super().__eq__(other)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self.__class__.__name__}: {self._val}>"
```

Then, let's create few instances of this class, set `s`  and list `lst`:

```py
a = MyObj("a", 123)
b = MyObj("b", 456)
d = MyObj("d", 456)  # same hash as b!

print("Creating set `s`")
s = set([a, b, d])

print("Creating list `lst`")
lst = [a, b, d]
```

This prints out:

```
Creating set `s`
<MyObj: a> calling __hash__
<MyObj: b> calling __hash__
<MyObj: d> calling __hash__
<MyObj: b> calling __eq__, other=<MyObj: d>
<MyObj: d> calling __eq__, other=<MyObj: b>
Creating list `lst`
```

- As you see, when creating sets, python calculates the hashes of the items. It also needs to call `__eq__`  if there is a hash collision (`b` and `d` have the same hash).

#### `x in collection` with a set

```py
>>> s
{<MyObj: a>, <MyObj: b>, <MyObj: d>}
>>> b in s
<MyObj: b> calling __hash__
True
>>> d in s
<MyObj: d> calling __hash__
<MyObj: b> calling __eq__, other=<MyObj: d>
<MyObj: d> calling __eq__, other=<MyObj: b>
True
```

- As you can see, python first calculates the hash of the `x`  when calling `x in someset`.
- If there is a hash collision, python *also* needs to call `__eq__`,  so it also calls `x == c`.

#### `x in collection` with a list

```py
>>> lst
[<MyObj: a>, <MyObj: b>, <MyObj: d>]
>>> a in lst
True
>>> b in lst
<MyObj: a> calling __eq__, other=<MyObj: b>
<MyObj: b> calling __eq__, other=<MyObj: a>
True
>>> d in lst
<MyObj: a> calling __eq__, other=<MyObj: d>
<MyObj: d> calling __eq__, other=<MyObj: a>
<MyObj: b> calling __eq__, other=<MyObj: d>
<MyObj: d> calling __eq__, other=<MyObj: b>
True
```

- As you can see from `a in lst`, python first checks `x is c`, and if that is True (identity check), it does not need to check the equality with `x == c`
- As you can see from `b in lst`, python checks the equality with `x == c` if the identity check evaluates to False.

---

### Notes related to this problem in particular

- As you can see, pytorch raises a RuntimeError if you try to compare `a == b` if a and b are tensors of different size.
- From source code of pytorch 2.0.1 it can be seen that the `torch.Tensor` hash "calculation" is just returning the `id(self)`:

```py
    def __hash__(self):
        # [comments omitted]
        return id(self)
```

- When doing `b  in list([a,b])`, or `b in [a,b]`, you will get an error as the logic will compare:

  - `id(b) is id(a)` -> False
  - `b == a` -> Raises RuntimeError, so b is never compared with b in the list.
- When doing `b in set([a,a,b])`, you will not get an error, as the set translates into a hashtable roughly like this `s = {id(a): a, id(b): b}` because `Tensor.__hash__` returns the id of the tensor, and the `b in s` does this:

  - "is `hash(b)`  same as any hash in the hashtable of `s`? Yes, it is!
  - `b is b` ? (is the b in the left hand side of `in`  same as the object in the set with the same hash as b?). This is True.
- **In summary**, the difference between checking `b in set([a,b])` and `b in [a,b]`  is that with lists you will check the `(x is c or x==c)` in *order* but with sets you'll *first* check the hash value, and then iterate over all the items in the set with *same* hash value  to check the `(x is c or x==c)` -- as `hash(b) != hash(a)`, you will (almost) *never* compare `b ==a` and will in most cases avoid the RuntimeError.

#### Workaround for this problem in particular

This answer starts to be long already, but basically, you could utilize the [torch.Tensor.size](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.size.html) attribute which is a subclass of tuple, and create a dictionary of sets (or lists) which stores tensors of different sizes.

Comment: I need to check if one nn.Module model's parameters are contained in another model by doing: ```python for p in model1.parameters(): 
                assert p in set(model2.parameters())```

Comment: @cangozpi is your comment related to this question somehow, or is it an another question? I cannot see nn.Module, model1 or model2 in the original question.

Comment: @cangozpi it is easy to test the premise of this answer, just reverse the contents of your list and see if it starts erroring out too.

Comment: @cangozpi btw is there some specific reason you would like to use *lists* (does the order matter), or did you just want to know if it is possible to use lists? This answer can be easily edited to use lists, too (just replace the set with a list and add with append).

Comment: Is it really "luck"? Is the hash method for tensors so bad that their two tensors have the same hash? (Only in that case, an equality comparison gets done).

Comment: @KellyBundy good point. According to  [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) "For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`."

Comment: The docs must have omitted hash comparison in case of sets and alike.. Then it would make sense: `b in set` would check the hashes and cause no evaluation of `b == a` but `b in list` would first fail the `b is a` check, continue by evaluating `b == a`  and then raise the RuntimeError.

Comment: Note that trying to make a `set` for numpy arrays will raise a `unhashable` error.  Same for a list.  Both are mutable (in contrast to a string or tuple).  Any hints as to how `Torch` defines its hash?

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments, especially @KellyBundy for making me think again. I've completely rewritten the answer keeping focus on trying to explain the differences of the behavior of the `in`  operator with sets and lists. This turned out to be much more interesting question than I first thought!

Comment: I think it's not relevant for the question, but the actual process for the set lookup differs from what your description sounds like. You left out the part where it uses the hash value to look only at certain entries in the hash table (i.e., the thing that makes the hash table fast). And it doesn't "first" find the subset of elements with matching hash and "then" iterates that subset. While it goes through those certain entries depending on the hash value, it checks whether those entries match the hash and are same/equal. (And it stops at success, so might not go through the whole "subset".)

Comment: I tried to underline that only a subset of the hashtable is ever used to do the `(x is c or x==c) ` check.  The outcome of the `in`  operator remains the same whether the subset would be taken "first" or if the `hash(x) == hash(c) and (x is c or x==c) `  is done for each element in the set.  Thanks for the review comments, I added some more clarifications!  Feel free to edit or add references :)

Comment: To be clear, the `hash(x) == hash(c) and (x is c or x==c)` is **not** done for each element in the set, only for each element in the set along the path determined by the hash and until a match or an empty entry. Which is usually only a few entries, regardless of how large the set is.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of tried to say that with (1) " iterate over that subset and do similar comparison with every element" and (2) "Only the elements in collection with same hash are ever compared" but I try to edit the answer to make that point clear!

Answer (score -1):

The difference is due to how python sets hash objects.

First a point of note, `torch.Tensor(n)` initializes a tensor with `n` objects without initializing values, which fills the tensor with small, random seeming values. You should use `torch.tensor` instead.

Now to your question.

For the list example. Say we have `tensor_list = [a,a,b]`. When we evaluate `b in tensor_list`, what we are actually doing is iterating over the elements in `tensor_list` and comparing the elements with `==`. Written out:

```py
b in tensor_list

# is actually doing

result = False
for item in tensor_list:
    if item == b:
        result = True
```

This is why you get the shape mismatch error.

Now for the set example. Python sets do not store objects - they store a hash based on the memory address of the object.

```py
tensor_set = set([a,a,b])
b in tensor_set

# this is basically the same as
tensor_set = set([id(a), id(a), id(b)])
id(b) in tensor_set
```

Since the comparison is based off a hash of the memory address, we don't actually compare tensors directly so we don't get the shape mismatch error.

This is an important distinction to be aware of, because it can lead to unexpected outcomes. For example:

```py
x = torch.tensor([1])
y = torch.tensor([1])

x == y
> True

x in set([y])
> False
```

The example `x in set([y])` evaluates to `False` because the set operation is checking the memory address of the object `x` against the memory address of the object `y`, not doing a comparison of the values of the two objects.

From your comments, it seems like you want to compare the parameters of two models. I'm not sure why you didn't just ask that question directly. You can do something like this:

```py
model1 = ...
model2 = ...

for p1 in model1.parameters():
    for p2 in model2.parameters():
        if p1.shape == p2.shape:
            if p1 == p2: # could also be torch.allclose(p1,p2)
                # do something
```

Comment: Your description of how `set` works is absolutely wrong.  It works on the *hash* of objects, not their id.

Comment: I explicitly wrote `Python sets do not store objects - they store a hash based on the memory address of the object.`, and later `Since the comparison is based off a hash of the memory address...`. I used the example of `tensor_set = set([id(a), id(a), id(b)])` for brevity, and annotated it as `basically the same as` for this reason. Maybe [this](https://www.amazon.com/Reading-Comprehension-Kids/s?k=Reading+Comprehension+for+Kids) will be of interest to you

Comment: The id is the memory address of the object.  And it is not used to create the hash, except for objects that explicitly define that as their hash.  Try this experiment: `a='a very long string'; b='a very long string'; id(a)==id(b); hash(a)==hash(b); a in set([b])`

Comment: @MarkRansom *"The id [...] is not used to create the hash"* - `id(obj) // 16` and `hash(obj)` consistently give me the same value. [Code](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3rfOTshRsFYBkanKJhiZXQVFmXolGRmJxhgZQTFNHITMFzFDQ11cwNFOwtVWAy2lCjICaBDMRAA).

Comment: @KellyBundy yes, `object` is one of those classes that explicitly uses the id as the hash - because it has no other choice!  There are no contents to base a hash on.

Comment: @MarkRansom The same happens [with my own class](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3Q5JzEouLFXwrnUG0FZcCEBQAWVz5SVkKtjBxDU2ugqLMvBKNjMTiDA2glKaOQmYKmKGgr69gaKZga6sAl9OEmA21AmYVAA), without *"explicitly define that as their hash"*.

Comment: @KellyBundy OK it's not explicit, but it is implicit because everything derives from `object`.  You need to override `__hash__` in your custom class if you want it to do something *useful*.

Comment: When hashing  immutable built-in types, (`int`, `float`, `str`, etc), python uses the content of the object. When hashing all other objects, python uses a hash of the memory address unless the object has explicitly defined `__hash__`. The question asked was about pytorch tensors. The pytorch `Tensor` class does not have a `__hash__` implementation. As a result, pytorch tensors are hashed based on the tensor's memory address.